# Adding Single quotes at the beginning and end of each string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to add single quotes at the beginning and end of all the strings in the given list and each item should be separated by a comma in notepad++

```
ANAND GABRIEL INDIA LIMITED
NARMAC MOTHER DAIRY HYDERABAD
LECTRICIT DE FRANCE
1 FB SUPPORT SERVICES P LTD
14 BRD AF GUWAHATI
1FB SUPPORT SERVICES PVT LTD
20 MICRONS LIMITED
20CUBE LOGISTICS PVT LTD
20TH CENTURY
21ST CENTURY MGNT SERV LTD
```

The result should be

```
'ANAND GABRIEL INDIA LIMITED',
'NARMAC MOTHER DAIRY HYDERABAD',
'LECTRICIT DE FRANCE',
'1 FB SUPPORT SERVICES P LTD',
'14 BRD AF GUWAHATI',
'1FB SUPPORT SERVICES PVT LTD',
'20 MICRONS LIMITED',
'20CUBE LOGISTICS PVT LTD',
'20TH CENTURY',
'21ST CENTURY MGNT SERV LTD'
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I got it, thanks added (.+) in find what and replaced it with ('\1') and then added comma by finding this [\n] and replaced it with [,\n]

Answer (score 4):

As per comments of OP,

> added (.+) in find what and replaced it with ('\1') and then added comma by finding this [\n] and replaced it with [,\n]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this : Find the string based on (.+) and replace with ('$0').

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You should provide more details along with your answer. Also, make sure you answer the question correctly (i.e. in NPP capture group use in replacement strings is with backslashes, not dollar signs). Thank you.

Comment: I tried with my Notepad++ editor, replacing with ('$0') will add quotes at beginning & ending of the selected string. If possible you can give a try... May be ('\1') will work...

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini: `\1` is very old notation, it's better to use `$1`. `\1` is used as backreference in the regex, not in the replacement part (even if it works for compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

Find the string `(.+)` and replace with `'$1',` and make sure to select "regular expression" checkbox in Find window.